# Can YOAST SEO fields be removed from custom post type

Tags: plugins, seo

The Yoast SEO plugin is great, but it seems to appear in more places then wanted (columns, custom post type pages, etc.). I want to remove this option because as it stands even when I ignore the fields if I save my custom post type I get several fields added to my database.

```
_yoast_wpseo_google-plus-description
_yoast_wpseo_linkdex
_yoast_wpseo_opengraph-description
_yoast_wpseo_redirect
_yoast_wpseo_canonical
_yoast_wpseo_sitemap-html-include
_yoast_wpseo_sitemap-prio
_yoast_wpseo_sitemap-include
_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-adv
_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-nofollow
_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-noindex
_yoast_wpseo_metadesc
_yoast_wpseo_title
```

So the goal is to not have them appear on the admin page at all so that they are not entered as values. Thanks in advance for any help with this

Comment: Just remove the meta boxes. Look up the source code where the get added, note their handles and then `remove_meta_box()` in some custom plugins.

Comment: The point isn't to edit the plugin, also, I don't want all meta_boxes removed, just within certain CPTs. I figured maybe there was a filter or something someone knew about

Comment: There is one in core: `add_meta_boxes` and similar (search core code base). Then just remove the meta boxes with above mentioned function. Try it, update your question with some code.

Comment: The answer was actually found here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/62579/12691

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So as noted in the comments above, I found a solution and used this code to do it:

```
function remove_yoast_metabox_reservations(){
    remove_meta_box('wpseo_meta', 'reservation', 'normal');
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'remove_yoast_metabox_reservations',11 );
```

In this instance, "reservation" was my custom post type.  And "wpseo_meta" was the ID of the metabox. So the same code can be used on any meta box on a post, page, cpt, etc.

Also credit belongs to Mamaduke for his post here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/62579/12691